# Proof-method: Show that if $n$ is not prime then $\Bbb Z /n\Bbb Z$ is not a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, field-theory, alternative-proof

The question pertains to the question in the title. That is,

> Show that if $n$ is not prime then $\Bbb Z /n\Bbb Z$ is not a field.

I realise that this has many duplicates, but my question is rather this;

> Why does it not suffice to say that if $n$ is not prime then $\lvert\Bbb Z /n\Bbb Z \rvert = n \neq p^m$ for some prime $p$ and integer $m$ and so is not a field by definition?

I realise this somewhat misses the *reason* why it's not a field, but would it suffice as an answer to this question?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Did you read the question?

Comment: You are right, a finite field must have $n=p^m$ elements. But also $\mathbb{Z}/p^m$ is not a field for $m>1$, but has $p^m$ elements. And you have to prove that a finite field must have $p^m$ elements, too - which is as difficult as proving the duplicate. And yes, I read the question, and still think, the main task is to show both directions, like in the duplicate.

Comment: Basically to prove that a finite field has $p^{m}$ elements requires knowing about prime subfields which in turn requires knowing when is $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ is a field (so you are assuming your result, essentially, to prove it, this way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A major reason why you cannot use this argument is that you seem to saying that because you know every finite field must have $p^{m}$ elements you get a contradiction.

However how do you know that you don't need this result in order to prove that finite field must have $p^{m}$ elements.

So does the proof of finite field must have $p^{m}$ elements, require the knowledge of the prime subfield and does this in turn require knowing that $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ is a field iff $n$ is prime...

Answer (score 2):

Because this is not enough to say that $\mathbb Z/9\mathbb Z $ is not a field, as $9$ is in fact of the form $p^m$ for a prime $p$ and positive integer $m$.

Comment: Thanks, didn't think about the case where $m \neq 1$.

Comment: No problem, also, the proof of that theorem is way harder than the one you want to prove right now

Comment: The proof of which? That fields have prime order?

Comment: No, that finite fields cardinal is a power of a prime number. This is different from saying that $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ is prime if and only if $n$ is prime. Finite fields are not all of the form $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ !